# Copying large files to a USB stick

Tags: rsync, cp, usb-drive

When I `mount` a USB stick and use `rsync` to copy a relatively large file onto it (`cp` has the same results, but progress bars are nice), it succeeds under 10 seconds. Then `umount`ing hangs for a few minutes before it finishes.

I assume this is because in the background the copying task is still running (at least under Windows it would take a lot more time than a few seconds). I cannot see anything outstanding in `htop`. When using `rsync` I'm expecting the copying process to last until actually finished. Can somebody provide an explanation on what is happening in the background here?
Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes writes are cached. Flush them to the disk with `sync`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [*Pheric*'s comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560908/copying-large-files-to-a-usb-stick#comment1042591_560908) notes: sometimes writes are cached. Flush them to the disk with the `sync` command.

If the problem is that a USB stick is writing too slow, another thing to reckon with is [the bandwidth of the PC hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_interface_bit_rates#Peripheral) itself.  For example, a user might have a USB 2 stick, (and wrongly assume that it can be written to at about 20MB/sec anywhere it's plugged in), so let's say that the user plugs it into the front of a 10 year old PC, (with slower USB 1.0 ports on the front), and is annoyed that the writes take ten times as long as expected -- but if the user instead uses the rear USB 2.0 ports, (connected to the motherboard), the writes might well be a full speed 20MB/sec.

USB stick hardware also varies.  For more details see 
[*What's the maximum typical speed possible with a USB2.0 drive?*](https://superuser.com/questions/317217/whats-the-maximum-typical-speed-possible-with-a-usb2-0-drive)